# Mordell like equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

This looks like a mordell like equation

X²=Y³-25056

How to solve it?
The exact equation is

(36x)²=(6y)³-25056

Is there any website has records of the equation x²=y³+k

For k>25000

Answer (score 5):

There are no integral points on this curve as established by SageMath. [Here is a code to run](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyr0KlUsFUoSyzSUKpQqFTS5HLNycksKMlMdi4tKkvV0K2MM1LQVqiIM1bQVTAyNTA109TLzCtJTS9KzIkvyAcyizU0AcTqFQo=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 4):

X=237225/196,  Y= $\pm$ 115541397/2744

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that OP wants a solution in integers.

Comment: @gerry myerson yes I want a solution in integers